# Scala generic math function for Int and BigInt with @specialized(Int)

Tags: performance, scala, generics

I'm new to scala and I wonder whether it is possible to define generic math function that works with both `BigInt` and `Int` and in the case of `Int` the arguments of function will be treated as primitives (without any boxing and unboxing in function body).

So, for example I can do something like

```
def foo[@specialized(Int) T: Numeric](a: T, b: T) = {
  val n = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
  import n._
  //some code with the use of operators '+-*/'
  a * b - a * a + b * b * b
}

//works for primitive Int
val i1 : Int = 1
val i2 : Int = 2
val i3 : Int = foo(i1, i2)

//works for BigInt
val b1 : BigInt = BigInt(1)
val b2 : BigInt = BigInt(2)
val b3 : BigInt = foo(b1, b2)
```

Here in `foo` I can use all math operators for both primitive `ints` and `BigInts` (that is what I need).  However, function `foo(Int, Int)` compiles to the following:

```
 public int foo$mIc$sp(int a, int b, Numeric<Object> evidence$1) {
        Numeric n = (Numeric)Predef..MODULE$.implicitly(evidence$1);
        return BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt((Object)n.mkNumericOps(n.mkNumericOps(n.mkNumericOps((Object)BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger((int)a)).$times((Object)BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger((int)b))).$minus(n.mkNumericOps((Object)BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger((int)a)).$times((Object)BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger((int)a)))).$plus(n.mkNumericOps(n.mkNumericOps((Object)BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger((int)b)).$times((Object)BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger((int)b))).$times((Object)BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger((int)b))));
}
```

instead of plain:

```
//this is what I really need and expect from `@specialized(Int)`
public int foo$mIc$sp(int a, int b) {
   return a * b - a * a + b * b * b;
}
```

which makes `@specialized(Int)` useless because the performance is unacceptably low with all these (un)boxings and unnecessary invocations `n.mkNumericOps(...)`.

So, is there a way to implement such generic function as `foo` that will compile to "just as is" code for primitive types?

Comment: Maybe implementing a macro is what you need. You can decide what code to be generated at compile time and it's not that hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the [Numeric](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) typeclass is not specialized.

If you want to do generic math with high performance, I highly recommend the [spire](https://github.com/non/spire) math library.

It has a very elaborate mathematical type class hierarchy, instead of just Numeric.

Here is how your example would look using spire:

```
import spire.implicits._ // typeclass instances etc.
import spire.syntax._    // syntax such as +-*/
import spire.algebra._   // typeclassses such as Field

def foo[@specialized T: Field](a: T, b: T) = {
  //some code with the use of operators '+-*/'
  a * b - a * a + b * b * b
}
```

Here you are saying that there has to be a [Field](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/spire/algebra/Field.scala) instance for T. Field refers to the [algebraic concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)).

Spire is highly modular:

- *spire.algebra* contains many well known algebraic concepts such as groups, fields etc, encoded as scala typeclasses
- *spire.syntax* contains the implicit conversions to add operators and other syntax to types for which typeclass instances are available
- *spire.implicits* contains instances for the typeclasses in spire.algebra for common types such as JVM primitives.

This is why you need the three imports.

Regarding the performance: if *your* code is specialized, and you are using primitives, the performance will be exactly the same as working with primitives directly.

Here is the code of the foo method when specialized for Int:

```
public int foo$mIc$sp(int, int, spire.algebra.Field<java.lang.Object>);
  Code:
     0: aload_3
     1: aload_3
     2: aload_3
     3: iload_1
     4: iload_2
     5: invokeinterface #116,  3          // InterfaceMethod spire/algebra/Field.times$mcI$sp:(II)I
    10: aload_3
    11: iload_1
    12: iload_1
    13: invokeinterface #116,  3          // InterfaceMethod spire/algebra/Field.times$mcI$sp:(II)I
    18: invokeinterface #119,  3          // InterfaceMethod spire/algebra/Field.minus$mcI$sp:(II)I
    23: aload_3
    24: aload_3
    25: iload_2
    26: iload_2
    27: invokeinterface #116,  3          // InterfaceMethod spire/algebra/Field.times$mcI$sp:(II)I
    32: iload_2
    33: invokeinterface #116,  3          // InterfaceMethod spire/algebra/Field.times$mcI$sp:(II)I
    38: invokeinterface #122,  3          // InterfaceMethod spire/algebra/Field.plus$mcI$sp:(II)I
    43: ireturn
```

Note that there is no boxing, and the invokeinterface calls will be inlined by the JVM.

Comment: Yes, I saw spire, but it is not an option in my case; I'm doing some computer algebra (basically in java; now considering to move to scala) and I have my own implementation of math classes (BigInteger (faster than  java's one), big fractions, modular arithmetic, polynomials,  etc. ). In Java I have to write several implementations e.g. for `extendedGCD(BigInteger, BigInteger)` and `extendedGCD(long, long)`/ I just want to avoid such things in scala and reuse the code (the code for gcd for `BigInteger` and `long` is identical since in scala I can define all math operators  *+-/ for BigInteger)

Comment: You can use spire typeclasses and syntax, and provide typeclass *instances* for your own types. That way you can write code once that works for both Long and your BigInteger type.